# arm64-w64-mingw32-gcc: command not found

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

I've followed some guide, claiming that mingw-w64 can be used, to compile an exe on Linux. I've installed it with `sudo apt install mingw-w64`. I doesn't seem to work.

```
┌──(parallels㉿kali-linux-2022-2)-[~]
└─$ aarch64-w64-mingw32-gcc
aarch64-w64-mingw32-gcc: command not found
                                                                                                                                                                                
┌──(parallels㉿kali-linux-2022-2)-[~]
└─$ arm64-w64-mingw32-gcc  
arm64-w64-mingw32-gcc: command not found
```

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to make an executable for Windows ARM rather than x86? The latter would be `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, I think.

Comment: Thx.. but yes my target is the aarch64 architecture.

Comment: I thought Windows on ARM can still run x86 binaries via emulation?

Comment: Not though emulation, but a translation layer. However... my use case is rather specific. I am doing cyber security and need to execute code from within the memory directly. Using x86_64 instructions, it will complain about invalid instructions.

Comment: MSYS2 can produce ARM executables (natively on Windows), but that uses Clang. Perhaps you can try cross-compiling with the native Linux Clang? `clang --target=aarch64-w64-mingw32`, with all the flags to disable the standard libraries. That should be enough to produce self-sufficient pieces of machine code, or do you need standard libraries? I could probably add support for Arm to [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), that would allow using the standard libraries.